# ejabberd MySQL connection error

Tags: mysql, odbc, xmpp, ejabberd

On trying to connect ejabberd with MySQL database an error is reported. This could be related to database name. After trying to connect another database without "-" character ejabberd server starts successfully with MySQL database.In ejabberd.cfg file I have uncommented following line to use MySQL database, with other changes

```
{odbc_server, {mysql, "localhost", "ejaaberddb-dev", "admin", "password"}}.
```

The error is as below:

```
@ejabberd_odbc:log:574 p1_mysql_conn: Failed changing to database "ejaaberddb-dev" : "#42000You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-dev' at line 1"
```

Could you please suggest how do I make connection to the above database from ejabberd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding "`" character around database name solved the problem.

```
{odbc_server, {mysql, "localhost", "`ejaaberddb-dev`", "admin", "password"}}.
```